# WAMP mod_rewrite not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I 'm using WAMP . mod_rewrite was turned on. But it doesn't work at all. I also set `AllowOverride` to `All`. Here my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
ReWriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?rt=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?rt=([^\s&]+)&id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Have any ideas? Thanks.